# How to create a JsonElement with its ValueKind equal to JsonValueKind.Null

Tags: c#

This question is specific to `System.Text.Json` namespace, not `Newtonsoft`. I am trying to write a unit test for a certain snippet in my code where I hae the below condition:

```
var objString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(objString);
var root = doc.RootElement;
if (root.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Null)
{// do something here}
```

I don't know a way of producing a `JsonElement` with its `ValueKind` equal to `JsonValueKind.Null`. I hae tried passing the below mentioned object in `obj` variable but they result in `JsonValueKind.Object`.

```
new MyClass()
{
    InnerMember = new InnerClass() { Data =  null }
}
```

Comment: if my class is th obj you serialize, then it's not Null. Data is null. https://dotnetfiddle.net/9zTa06

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got `JsonValueKind.Object` because you are looking at the *root* element. There is only one case where the root element has a kind of `Null`, and that is when the entire json string is:

```
null
```

To demonstrate:

```
var doc = JsonDocument.Parse("null");
var root = doc.RootElement;
if (root.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Null)
{
    // this will run
}
```

If you want `JsonSerializer.Serialize` to produce `null`, just pass in `null`:

```
object obj = null;
var objString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
```